# Maintain order within partition and also across partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a sorted `pyspark` `dataframe`

```
Col1 Col2
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     B
5     B
6     B
```

I want all As to be in one file and B in another while maintaining the exact order as above.

When i write this using the following statement:

```
Data.coalesce(1).write.mode(“overwrite”).partitionBy(“col2”).csv(mypath)
```

`Pyspark` shuffles up the data within each individual file changing the order of the sorted `dataframe`.

Can someone help with this?

Note :using a `shuffleWithinpartition` might not be possible, because i am able to create this sorted order in the table above using a complex logic, not just a single column. Table above is just a dummy example.

Comment: monotonically increasing ID column to your DataFrame using the monotonically_increasing_id() function. 
 -----------------------------------------------------
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
df_with_id = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
repartitioned_df = df_with_id.repartition("col2")
sorted_df = repartitioned_df.orderBy("id")
sorted_df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("col2").csv(mypath)

Comment: @DebugCode, where do i place the coalesce (1) statement in your code, coz i want a single csv file under each partition folder

Comment: you could just repartition the df on that column -- `df.repartition('col2').write...`

Answer (score 0):

I think if it is used as follows, the data will be sorted and each file will be in a folder:

```
num_partitions = Data.select("Col2").distinct().count()
sorted_data = Data.repartition(num_partitions, "Col2").orderBy("Col2")
coalesced_data = sorted_data.coalesce(1)
coalesced_data.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Col2").csv(mypath)
```

Answer (score 0):

@ind_1617:

By adding coalesce(1) on the sorted_df, see the resulting dataframe is coalesced into a single partition before writing it as a CSV file.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

    df_with_id = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    repartitioned_df = df_with_id.repartition("col2")
    sorted_df = repartitioned_df.orderBy("id")

    # Coalesce(1) statement added here
    coalesced_df = sorted_df.coalesce(1)

    coalesced_df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("col2").csv(mypath)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the repartition method instead of coalesce. repartition allows you to specify the number of output partitions, which you can set to the number of distinct values in Col2 to ensure that each value of Col2 will be in a separate partition. Here's an example:

```
num_partitions = Data.select("Col2").distinct().count()
Data.repartition(num_partitions, 
"Col2").write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Col2").csv(mypath)
```

Comment: This method does not seem to ensure a single file inside each partition folder. I get multiple files inside each partition folder, instead i want only one

Comment: please answer the above

Comment: coalesce(1) function call before the repartition call ensures that the data is first collapsed into a single partition to ensure that each partition folder contains only one file

    num_partitions = Data.select("Col2").distinct().count()
    Data.coalesce(1).repartition(num_partitions, 
    "Col2").write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Col2").csv(mypath)

Comment: The above mentioned line still causes shuffling from the original order within part files. So this does not work